# C diff individual functions or parse to separate files

Tags: c, diff

I have two files that were based on common source but branched off and functions got changed and reordered. Now I would like to converge the two files into one again.

Is there a way I can diff the two files function by function rather than linearly from beginning to end?

Alternatively if there is a simple way (rather than writing my own parser) to output each function into its own file and then I can easily diff the two corresponding directories?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are on unix machine and have git then just merge both the files using `git merge`

Comment: I'm not aware of any off the shelf tools open source to intelligently compare C functions, but a number of IDE's offer this ability. Checkout http://www.devart.com/codecompare/

Comment: As you seem to recognize, it is the reordering that will wreak the most havoc on your merge effort.  I do not know any tool that interprets the structure of your source to perform a function-by-function merge, so your two main alternatives are to split each function into a separate file or to reorder them into a consistent order.  I don't know any tool for the former, but can you do it by hand?  For the latter, some IDEs (e.g. Eclipse) make it pretty easy to physically reorganize source files.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this yourself will require a lot of coding.  On the other hand, this is what source code management systems specialize in.

I would suggest either using git directly by using `git merge`.  If you do not have git, you can use tools like SVN and CVS, but these would require that you create a repo, import one of the files into it and then replace it with the second file to allow it to report changes to you.  More work in the end. :)

Comment: Pretty sure using CVS nowadays is a bad idea; but otherwise, I agree. There's also Mercurial and Fossil, to list some more alternatives.

Comment: @TimČas Even if CVS isn't a bad idea, I sure wouldn't use it. :)

Comment: Going through a source control system seems like a major roundabout to get the functionality I want. I would've imagined, with the C language being around for decades that there would be at least a way to parse C files into separate functions!

Comment: With git you do not need to import it.  Just use git merge directly.